# Is accessing application resources via the Resource class same as accessing via the context?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-context

Wile writing code I found out the that I can the access the string resources via calling the `getString()` function on both `context`

```
val string = context.getString(...)
```

and `context.resources`

```
val string = context.resources.getString(...)
```

Which is the right way to do it? Why the two ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which is the right way to do it?

Either is fine. The implementation of `getString()` is:

```java
    @NonNull
    public final String getString(@StringRes int resId) {
        return getResources().getString(resId);
    }
```

(from [the source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Context.java;drc=master))

So, they both do the same thing.

> Why the two ways?

`getString()` is used a lot. Presumably, they added a helper method to `Context` to simplify access to string resources. However, while they do that for a couple of resource types, many others are only available via the full `Resources` object.